# Searching some data in json

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I wanna searching some data in json. The API which I wanna used doesn't support search method. I have an idea to download all data but it will be too much for user and it will be cost too much in data usage. Is there any other way how I search it? This is the [API](http://api.tabloidnova.com/1/subscribe/get?api_key=259225f04f4015746b03e1bad6238eaa&format=json&channel_id=110) and for username and password just use "foo". Oh yes, I wanna implement it in Windows Phone 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario:
- Your app wants to retrieve some data from a remote/web source.
- The remote source returns more than your app wants.
- The remote source is beyond your control and can't be reconfigured to just return what you want.

The way to handle this (as I have done on a number of other apps/services*) is to create your own "proxy" service to do the searching/filtering/querying for you.

By creating your own service to act as a proxy between the app and the 3rd party service you can:

- return only the data the app wants/needs
- preformat the data that is passed to the app
- add any intermediary processing or filtering of the data that is returned to the app
- update the code that does the formatting/processing of the data returned from the 3rd party in a single place and at any time, without having to update installed apps.

Yes, there is a cost to hosting and managing your own service. Exactly how much and whether this is something you want to do will depend on your circumstances.

* The services I have for this do things like take an RSS feed, strip out only the contents that are required, reformat the content for display on the requesting device and return the data in a format that is easy for the app to work with (typically objects that the apps knows, serialized as JSON). I'll also add appropriate caching and compression support on the proxy server.

Comment: I never build my own web services. Can you tell me how I build it and maybe a link for tutorial?

Comment: @blueboyz try this for starters http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api